# Removing observations in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a dataframe with variable violation1 which contains types of violation.

For certain string, I have used the code below to exclude them.

```
camparking <- camparking[ grep("OTHER", camparking$Violation1, invert = TRUE) , ]
camparking <- camparking[ grep("BL- BIKE LANE", camparking$Violation1, invert = TRUE) , ]
camparking <- camparking[ grep("CENTER STRIP/ISLAND", camparking$Violation1, invert = TRUE) , ]
camparking <- camparking[ grep("NOT IN METER SPACE", camparking$Violation1, invert = TRUE) , ]
camparking <- camparking[ grep("OVRNGHT HEAVY VEHCLE", camparking$Violation1, invert = TRUE) , ]
camparking <- camparking[ grep("PEDESTRIAN ZONE", camparking$Violation1, invert = TRUE) , ]
camparking <- camparking[ grep("SNOW/WEATHER EMRGY", camparking$Violation1, invert = TRUE) , ]
camparking <- camparking[ grep("DRIVEWAY", camparking$Violation1, invert = TRUE) , ]
camparking <- camparking[ grep("HANDICAP RAMP", camparking$Violation1, invert = TRUE) , ]
camparking <- camparking[ grep("OVER 1FT FROM CURB", camparking$Violation1, invert = TRUE) , ]
camparking <- camparking[ grep("TAXI STAND", camparking$Violation1, invert = TRUE) , ]
```

[image]

I used summary() to summarize the total count of each violation type, the excluded strings show zero as their values.

When I used this result to plot the bar chart, the bar chart would show those values which contains zero.

[image]

1) Is there an way to remove those strings so that it wouldn't show up in the bar chart? ex. remove BL-BIKE LANE or TAXI STAND?

2) Is there an way to create an box on the blank spot on that graph where I can list the types of violations?

Comment: I'm 99% sure you can just use `droplevels(camparking$Violation1)` and plot that.

Comment: You could use something like `which` or `>=`, ... paired with `[]`

Comment: droplevels(camparking$Violation1) did not drop those zero value strings..

Comment: Please post `dput(camparking$Violation1)`

Comment: As etienne notes, you need to provide the structure of the data. I'm guessing that the issue is that you have a factor variable not a character variable.

Comment: Yes those are factor variables, not a character variables. Do I use as.character() to covert them into character variables to delete those 0 value rows?